# Protein supplements for over weight people

Tags: protein, body-fat, supplements

Is it good to have protein supplements when over weight ? Is it possible to gain muscles by having proteins while having extra body fat ?

Comment: I dont understand why people are down voting legitimate questions. Gave you a +1 and @user1013159 is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you're unfit, it is possible to gain muscle while losing body fat, but this gets harder the more fit you get. If you have a low intake of protein and if you replace something with the protein supplement (rather than just adding it to your diet), then it can be beneficial.

Comment: I'm thinking to get this one to have as the very first thing in the morning http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B00GSR3LP0

Comment: Protein is a very simple product, all you want is protein (more is better), and some kind of taste that's ok (they all taste a lot better with milk than with water though.) That one is quite expensive imo, the one I buy that tastes decently is 1 kg/12 pounds.

Comment: I see ,would mind to share that product ?

Comment: It's a local brand here in Sweden, it doesn't seem to be sold anywhere else. But considering the fact that protein powder is processed milk, it shouldn't be any more expensive in UK than in Sweden, although many brands charge extra to get money from customers who aren't aware of prices or who think that their mystery chemicals will make a difference :)